# Running Anaconda Command From Visual Studio Code's power shell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I know it's possible to run anaconda commands from anaconda prompt but it is more convenient to run it from the powershell of visual studio code like basic python where we can install the package by simply writing 'pip' command. Is there any similar way for anaconda in vscode?

Comment: May [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) help?

Comment: I tried to run the conda create command according to the article but still shows "the term conda is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file ... "

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't install conda to your PATH then this is by design of conda itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can just activate your conda inside a VS Code terminal:

```
/path/to/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
```

Then you can use the same commands you can with anaconda prompt, like

```
conda activate env
```

for example